# Spring Boot Admin: 401 on Jolokia endpoint causes authentication to fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am using [Spring-Boot-Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) in order to monitor a SpringBoot app whose actuator endpoints are secured using basic auth. The required credentials are transferred to Spring-Boot-Admin (SBA) like described in the [documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.4/#_securing_client_actuator_endpoints). SBA itself is also secured using `spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login` and the provided SecurityConfiguration (based on the documentation & sample apps, see [Github Repo](https://github.com/geld0r/spring-boot-admin-ui) for code).
Both the app to be monitored and SBA are deployed via docker.

Logging in to SBA works fine and I can see the application state as well as the health results. For some content I see a nested login mask though. When I click on "Logging" or "JMX" I am redirected to the login mask: [image: Embedded login mask]

In the browsers network tab I can see that a 401 is returned for the `/jolokia` endpoint. All requests after that seem to be forwarded to the login page.

I have the following questions:

1. Why am I logged out if one request to the application fails? Is that a bug?
2. What is the source of the 401? SBA or my app? I know that SBA proxies requests to the app. According to the access logs from my app no request to `/jolokia` is done when I login to SBA. Does this mean that the 401 is returned by SBA directly? Its logs contain nothing of relevance though.
3. Accessing the `/jolokia` endpoint directly works fine. It even works when I use the same (proxied) URL that SBA uses (e.g. `http://XXX:8090/api/applications/XXX/jolokia/`). What is different when this is executed from within SBA?

I've tried to find more error details in SBA but so far failed to find the proper logging options. They either contain nothing relevant or way too much information (e.g. Spring Security) that doesn't seem to be relevant. Logging the full response would probably help...

Edit: I just realized, that the request to the `/jolokia` endpoint actually contains a different cookie (Cookie:JSESSIONID=4E51B84AE15A6890500F967B23EB92AC) than the requests to the working endpoints (e.g. `/metrics`). Thats weird, but probably explains why the `/jolokia` endpoint returns a 401. Now the question is: Why does it send a different cookie`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various things, but in the end couldn't solve this.

I instead ended up with a different configuration: No security at all for the endpoints (`management.security.enabled=false`), but exposing them on a different port (`management.port=8081`). This management endpoint is blocked for external access to the system completely.

With that, SBA behaves nicely and the application is still secure. In the end, its a much simpler setup which is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I could access all actuator endpoints, but everything with /jolokia would not be authorized. Although my security setup is a different to yours, i assume the problem is the same.

When i digged into this I found out that jolokia runs in its own servlet separately from the spring boot application. Maybe therefore you have different sessions!?

My Security Config tries to match this expression

****.mvcMatchers("/actuator/**").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','SBA')")****,

but the SBA user role was not able to access Jolokia. It always matched the last fallback-rule where only Admin was allowed.

In my case the context- and servlet-path of the jolokia servlet would be stripped away from the request path before trying to match it to my security config. Then it would only match "/list" against my MVC matchers instead of "/actuator/jolokia/list" which would then not fit as expected.

Unfortunately I do not have a fix for your problem. For my case i added a requestMatchers rule which is a little bit less opinionated and would still match:

**.requestMatchers(request -> request.getRequestURI().contains("/actuator/jolokia/")).access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','SBA')")**

instead of

****.mvcMatchers("/actuator/**").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','SBA')")****